# Complex function maps into lines and circles

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

We have the following function: $$f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z-i}$$

What is $f$ of the real line (so $f(\mathbb{R}))$?

What we did in the solutions was:

$$f(\infty) = 1 \\
f(0) = 1/i = -i\\
f(1) =0\\$$

Then we said:
$$|z-(a+bi)| = r\\
|1-a-bi| = r\implies (1-a)²+b²=r² \implies a = 1/2 \\
|-i-a-bi| = r\implies a²+(b+1)^2 = r²\implies b = -1/2\\
|a+bi| = r \implies\\
\implies a²+b² = r² \implies r = \sqrt{1/4 + 1/4} = \\
=\sqrt{2}/2 \implies |z-(1/2-i/2)| = \sqrt{2}/2\\$$

However I dont understand what we just did above. Can somebody explain what the procedure was and why. What would $f$ do to the imaginary line $\mathbb{I}$ or maybe the outside of the unit circle?

I really need help with understanding the procedure for exercises like this one.

Comment: The solution first determines that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a circle. You can determine this by looking at the asymptotic behavior of $f(z)$. Then they determine three points on the circle, i.e ${f(0), f(1), f(\infty)}$, and use the three given points to calculate the radius and center.

Comment: @MattE. That procedure seems to be based on knowing the answer already and then providing plausibility rather than an actual procedure for arriving at the answer.

Comment: @SuzuHirose The quoted solution relies on recognizing $\,\frac{z-1}{z-i}\,$ as a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) and using its (presumably known) properties. There is no plausibility argument involved.

Answer (score 1):

The solution outlined in OP's question relies on understanding of the [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), which implies that $\,f(\mathbb R)\,$ is a [generalized circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle). To find it, it's enough to find $3$ points on it, which in this case were determined to be $1, -i, 0$. Its center lies at the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of segments $(0,1)$ and $(0,-i)$ which is the point $\frac{1-i}{2}$, and its radius is $\left|\frac{1-i}{2}\right|=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

The following is an alternative solution, without assuming prior knowledge of Möbius transformations.

Let the image of $\,z\,$ be $\,w=f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z-i} \iff z = \frac{i w-1}{w-1}\,$. When $z \in \mathbb R \iff z = \bar z$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{i w-1}{w-1} = \frac{-i \bar w-1}{\bar w-1}
\\ \iff\quad\quad (iw-1)(\bar w - 1) = (w-1)(-i\bar w- 1)
\\ \iff\quad\quad iw\bar w - iw - \bar w + 1 = -i w \bar w - w + i \bar w + 1
\\ \iff\quad\quad 2iw\bar w + (1-i) w - (1+i)\bar w = 0
\\ \iff\quad\quad 2w\bar w - (1+i) w - (1-i)\bar w = 0
\\ \iff\quad\quad \big((1+i)w - 1\big)\big((1-i)\bar w - 1\big) - 1 = 0
\\ \iff\quad\quad \big|(1+i)w - 1\big|^2 = 1
\\ \iff\quad\quad \big|2w - (1-i)\big|^2 = 2
\\ \iff\quad\quad \left|w - \frac{1-i}{2}\right| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$

The latter is the equation of a circle of radius $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ centered at $\frac{1-i}{2}$ (which, for verification, matches the result obtained using the other method).

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=t$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and then
$$ f(z)=\frac{t-1}{t-i}=\frac{(t-1)(t+i)}{t^2+1}=\frac{t(t-1)}{t^2+1}+\frac{t-1}{t^2+1}i. $$
Let
$$ x=\frac{t(t-1)}{t^2+1}, y=\frac{t-1}{t^2+1} $$
and then
$$ (x-\frac12)^2+(y+\frac12)^2=\frac12 $$
which is a circle centered at $(\frac12,-\frac12)$ with radius $\frac1{\sqrt2}$.